# Java - How to Loop and Print Values From 2 HashMaps on the Same Line?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I found related questions but I'm not sure how to do this using a for loop. I have two HashMaps that are filled by user input. Both maps have matching keys. I'm trying to come up with a final report that would pull the matching key and the values for each individual map, all printed on the same line. As of right now, my code is printing the first HashmMap(Products) followed by the values second MashMap(Price).

Current Output

```
Priority Product  Price

1 apple  
2 banana   
3 orange  
$ 43.81   
$ 69.64   
$ 96.35
```

I thought about creating a 3rd hashmap and combining all values into one, but I'm not sure if that will really work.

Desired Output

```
Priority Product Price

1 apple  $ 43.81  
2 banana $ 69.64   
3 orange $ 96.35
```

My Code

```
import java.util.*; 


public class Testing 
{

    String products;
    int priority;
    double price; 


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner 

    HashMap<Integer, String> pMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); // Product HashMap

    HashMap<Integer, Double> priceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(); //Price HashMap

    Random r = new Random(); //Random number


    public void testingItems()
    {


        for ( int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
            {
                //Ask for user input to Add product name and product priority 

                    System.out.println("\nEnter a Product"); 
                    products = keyboard.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("\nEnter a Priority");
                    priority = keyboard.nextInt();

                    price = (r.nextDouble() * 100); 
                    //System.out.print(price);


                    keyboard.nextLine(); 


                //*** HASHMAPS *** 

                    //Add product and priority to HashMap 



                    pMap.put(priority, products);

                    priceMap.put(priority, price); 



                    System.out.println("Product: "+ products + "\t\t" + "Priority: " +  priority + "\n\n" + "Price:" + " $ "+ price);
            }


                    System.out.println("\nPriority  " + "  Product  " + "  Price");
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

                    for (Integer key: pMap.keySet())
                    {                                                                                   
                        System.out.println(key + "\t" + pMap.get(key));
                    }
                        for (Integer key2: priceMap.keySet()){
                            System.out.println("$ " + priceMap.get(key2));
                        }

            }
    }
```

Comment: Could you refine your question, I think you're saying that you're trying to iterate 2 [ arbitrary ] maps and print their respective values to the same line?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I was having trouble iterating through two maps, while making sure that the output values would print on the same line.

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't preserve insertion order, meaning there's no guarantee your two key loops will run in the same order. If you want to stick with 2 maps, consider using [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your own sanity, you probably want to introduce a `Product` class that has a priority, name and price. But to answer the question as asked:

```
pMap.forEach((p, n) -> System.out.format("%d %s $%2f\n", p, n, priceMap.get(p)));
```

---

If you created a `Product` class (recommended), whose *natural ordering* (`implements Comparable<Product>`) was defined by `priority`, you could store them in a `TreeSet<Product>`. Iteration over the set would then be in priority order.

Comment: Thank you!! This is a really cool, one line solution. I like this because it also helps me with another formatting issue that I'm working on. And yes, I would definitely be adding a Product class. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `print` instead of `println` if you don't want a newline (which you don't since you want to keep text on the same line. Just remember to end with a println() or `\n` to get the next record on the next line).

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over both the maps at the same time and access the elements according to their priority indexes.

```
for (int priority : pMap.keySet()) {
     System.out.print(priority);   //prints the priority
     System.out.print(pMap.get(priority));  // prints the product for the priority
     System.out.print(priceMap.get(priority));  //prints the price 
     System.out.println();  // changes the line
}
```